# What is this error Initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an expression of incompatible type 'void' in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am changing the deployment target from iOS 8 to iOS 10 and it is showing an error like **Initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an expression of incompatible type 'void'** in the line

```
- (BOOL)presentAuthorizationWithURL:(NSURL *)URL session:(id<OIDAuthorizationFlowSession>)session {
if (_authorizationFlowInProgress) {
return NO;
}
_authorizationFlowInProgress = YES;
_session = session;
if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
    if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
        SFSafariViewController *safariVC =
        [[[self class] safariViewControllerFactory] safariViewControllerWithURL:URL];
        safariVC.delegate = self;
        _safariVC = safariVC;
        [_presentingViewController presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        return YES;
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
 BOOL openedSafari = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
 if (!openedSafari) {
[self cleanUp];
NSError *safariError = [OIDErrorUtilities errorWithCode:OIDErrorCodeSafariOpenError
                                        underlyingError:nil
                                            description:@"Unable to open Safari."];
[session failAuthorizationFlowWithError:safariError];
}
return openedSafari;
}
```

This is the previous method, can I change this entire method to void?

What is the error exactly and how can I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-openURL:options:completionHandler:` returns no `BOOL` value back to you at all – where did you get the idea about that?

Comment: Previously I am initialising like this  BOOL openedSafari = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]; and i changed the deployment target from iOS 8 to 10., openURL is deprecated in iOS 10 then again i initialising like this   BOOL openedSafari = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Comment: use the `completionHandler:` then, that could do the job for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are calling has this signature:

```
- (void)  openURL:(NSURL *)url
          options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion;
```

It returns `void`, so you can't assign that to a `BOOL` variable.  Instead, you need a `completionHandler` block that determines what to do when the method completes.

Before iOS 10, this was the method to call:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

That method does return a `BOOL`, but it's deprecated now.

You'll need to change your code to something like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL options:@{}
   completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
  if (success) {
    // do whatever you do on success
  }
  else {
    // do whatever you do on failure
  }
}];
```

See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/ for more details of how to deal with this change.

Comment: Previously i am initialising like this  BOOL openedSafari = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]; and i am changing the deployment target from iOS 8 to iOS 10. openURL is deprecated differently in iOS 10 then again i changed the initialisation as above..

Comment: Okay., Got you @Kristopher Johnson. I can change the method as well., Right?

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL *)url 
        options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options 
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion;
```

doesn't return a value, it returns `void` which is nothing.

Comment: But I am using this method   - (BOOL)presentAuthorizationWithURL:(NSURL *)URL session., It should return some value, Right?